# How can I get a deterministic topological sort in Petgraph?

Tags: rust, non-deterministic, petgraph

I'm using Petgraph's [`toposort`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/algo/fn.toposort.html) function to get a sorted list of the graph's nodes. `toposort` does not however guarantee that all nodes at the same level will be returned in a consistent deterministic order. Is there some other option within Petgraph that will return the nodes in a deterministic order, or would I need to write my own function? (If so, any pointers?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `toposort` (and other algorithms) are sensitive to the order that graph nodes and edges are created. I had been feeding the graph with data from a `HashMap`, which cannot be iterated in a deterministic order. By switching my data to a `BTreeMap` the nodes and edges are created in a reliable order, and then algorithms like `toposort` give deterministic results.